# Error in MySql host after adding Master page in asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

i create a web application that it's get data from mysql and display in gridview. Different pages for different data. 
But now i added menu items that will be easy for user to navigate.

For that i added sitemap, Master page.

My default.aspx act as a login page.
After adding this master page, when i try to open application it shows below error message.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Configuration Error
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

Source Error:


Line 178:    <siteMap>
Line 179:      <providers>
Line 180:        <add name="MySqlSiteMapProvider" type="MySql.Web.SiteMap.MySqlSiteMapProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="/" />
Line 181:      </providers>
Line 182:    </siteMap>


Source File: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Config\machine.config    Line: 180
```

Below is default.aspx page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Main.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="SimERP._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        .style1
        {
            width: 55px;
        }
        .style2
        {
            width: 55px;
            height: 32px;
        }
        .style3
        {
            height: 32px;
        }
    </style>

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<body>
<link href="CSS/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

                    <tr>
                      <td width="20px" class="style2"></td>
                      <td class="style3">User Name</td>
                      <td class="style3">Password</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td align=center class="style1">
                          &nbsp;</td>
                      <td align=left>
                          <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                      <td align=l>
                          <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

           <tr>
                      <td height="60px" align="center">
                          <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnSignIn" runat="server" 
                              ImageUrl="~/images/SignIn.jpg" onclick="imgBtnSignIn_Click" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
    </form>
</body>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: delete form tags and change like this applicationName="/default.aspx"

Comment: i need to delete form tags in default.aspx, where can i change applicationName?

Comment: end of your <add name="MySqlSiteMapProvider"

Comment: line is in  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Config\machine.config. So i think i cannot change that.

Answer (score 15):

MySql installed a default siteMap provider in the machine config:

```
<siteMap>
  <providers>
    <add name="MySqlSiteMapProvider" type="MySql.Web.SiteMap.MySqlSiteMapProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</siteMap>
```

Added following to  web.config under the system.web section to exclude it

```
<siteMap>
<providers> <remove name="MySqlSiteMapProvider" />  </providers>
</siteMap>
```

Comment: You Saved my time. Alas! I can give more than 1 point. Thanks!